# Не грузится иконка сайта

Tags: html, html5, веб-программирование, favicon

Сделал сайт, добавил мета-тег для иконки, но он не действует. В консоли ошибок нет. Сама иконка доступна по ссылке.

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://blackbots.ru/files/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
```

Адрес сайта: [blackbots.ru](http://blackbots.ru)

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Домен не прилинкован ошибка. А так скорее всего вы кеш не сбросили.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Лично у меня проблем с Вашей иконкой нет, то есть на Вашем сайте она отображается и по ссылке на иконку тоже прекрасно все переходит.

Однако я использую данную конструкцию(т.е. по сути тоже самое что и у Вас), разница в том, что картинка берется по ссылке не с какого-то сайта, а с самого компьютера, все работает прекрасно, применял кучу раз.

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/icon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
```

Так что попробуйте скачать нужную картинку и вставить ее с компа, если все получится, то значит какие-то проблемы с доменом, у которого вы берете картинку.